# Manage access to an s3 folder in the browser - best practice?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a bucket configured as a website and the bucket policy allows public access to all folders in the bucket except the '/_admin/' folder.  Only a specific Iam user making requests is allowed access to '/_admin/'.  This is for backend management of the website, so I am serving up html, js, css, etc to the user.  Right now I am using the aws javascript sdk to sign every url to a js/css/img src/href link and then update that attribute, or create it.  (This means hardly anything is getting cached because the signature changes each time you access it.)  I've proven this concept and I can access the files by signing every single url in my webpages, but it seems an awkward way to build a website.

Is there a way I can just add some kind of access header to each page that will be included in every request?  If so, will this also apply to all ajax type requests as well?

Comment: *I have a bucket configured as a website...sign every url to a js/css/img src/href link* I don't follow... the [website endpoints don't interpret signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html).  Are you using a bucket as a web site, but using the REST endpoint, instead, or...?

Comment: I was using the SDK to sign URLs so that users could access content behind '/_admin'.  I have a better way now.  I'll post it later.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with to solve this problem.  I modified my bucket policy to deny all anonymous access to '/_admin/' unless it is from my main account id, a specific Iam user, or unless the referrer url matches a specific token. After the user authenticates from a publicly accessible page on my site, I generate a new token, then use the sdk to modify the bucket policy with the value of that new token.  (I'll probably also add another condition with an expires date.)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-domain-structure/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAdminWithToken",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::AWS-USER-ID:user/IAM-USER",
                "arn:aws:iam::AWS-USER-ID:root"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-domain-structure/_admin/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": "*?t=a77Pn"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

In each page I use javascript to prepend each link/href with the new querystring (?t=a77Pn ...or the new generated token).
Edit:  That was really a pain.  Links kept breaking, so ultimately I went with the solution below, plus an added condition of an expiration date.  Works much better.

Another option is to modify the bucket policy to only allow access from a certain ip address.  This would eliminate having to modify all links/hrefs and keep the url clean.  Still open to a better idea, but this works for now.